# How to show that the dimension of a quotient space in the field of polynomials is not finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quotient-spaces

I have to show that if I have a quotient of the form $\mathbb{K}[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]/\langle f_1,f_2,\dots,f_s\rangle$, $\operatorname{char}(\mathbb{K})\not=0$, and on which the class of $[x_i^l]$ is not zero for every $i\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and for all $l>0$, then said space can't have finite dimension. The problem is I can't find a proof that in that case said monomials will be independent, supposing they really are. Any help?

Comment: If $s=n$ and each $f_i$ is of the form $x_i - a$ with $a \ne 0$ then the condition is satisfied but this quotient is just the ground field.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved it.